# Logic of id of element in OpenUI5

Tags: routes, sapui5

In my app a use Component to instantiate views: for example in routing target I have

```
detail_article: {
                    viewName: "DetailArticle",
                    viewLevel: 6,
                    viewId: "DetailArticle"

                }
```

The id of the view is `__component0---DetailArticle`. Why not only `DetailArticle`?

I have updated my routing using the new mode with `targets` http://openui5.tumblr.com/post/113243652527/new-openui5-preview-release-1-28 and afther this I show that the view id has changed (before it is without `__component0---`)

But my question is moore general: what id the logic that regulates tha id setting?

Edit:
I looked for the differences in the debut between old routing https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/688f36bd758e4ce2b4e682eef4dc794e.html  and new routing http://openui5.tumblr.com/post/113243652527/new-openui5-preview-release-1-28 :

```
//old routing
{
   Id="splitApp-Detail"
   _sOwnerId="__component0"
   mAggregation={
      pages=[   
          Id="DetailArticle",
          _sOwnerId="__component0"
      ]
   }
}


//new routing
{
   Id="splitApp-Detail"
   _sOwnerId="__component0"
   mAggregation={
      pages=[  
          Id="__component0---DetailArticle"
          _sOwnerId="__component0"
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, how can I set the id of the `component0` so that I can call exactly the view?

Comment: The IDs are prefixed with its owners ID in order to prevent ID collisions. This is done automatically except when you use JSViews. There you have to call this.createId("") to get it prefixed. It's a good question why this wasn't done before using targets but it's a better practice to do so.

Comment: Have you tried to call byId("DetailArticle") function of your component? This gives you your detail view by its Id and the prefixing is added for you internally.

Comment: Thankyou @TimGerlach .   I have upadated my Q; only changing the routing method the id change adding the prefix... `sap.ui.getCore().byId("DetailArticle");` returns undefined

Comment: A new routing bug..?

Comment: Have you tried `this.byId("DetailArticle")` in your component to get the detail view? From outside the component you can use `sap.ui.getCore().getComponent("<componentId>").byId("DetailArticle)` or `sap.ui.getCore().getRootComponent().byId("DetailArticle")`